# Can not create records in a custom module for normal users (can only created by admin access rights)

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I installed odoo 12 and create a custom module
I got this message while creating a record by the normal user

Sorry, you are not allowed to access this document. Only users with the following access level are currently allowed to do that:
- Administration/Access Rights

(Document model: ir.rule) - (Operation: read, User: 6)

Please help me, to fix this

Comment: You didn't define access right for you Model, you should define access rights for every model you created, groups that have access to it, check any `ir.model.access.csv` in any module in Odoo addons you will understand what you should do

Answer (score 3):

Please go through the below link.

https://medium.com/@reedrehg/becoming-a-superuser-in-odoo-12-0-f6fc2de3a62e

If you are aware of the Odoo 10 and below versions, you will understand this.

Apart from all of this add access rights for newly creating classes in Odoo on file `ir.model.access.csv`.

For example:

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_industry_section,access_industry_section,model_industry_section,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: already have a ir.model.access.csv file like this id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_test_test,test.test,model_test_test,,1,1,1,1

Comment: Restart the server, update the app list and update the module. It should work. Else paste your error log here.

Comment: Here is the server log -->>2019-10-21 12:29:19,276 8537 INFO sample odoo.addons.base.models.ir_model: Access Denied by ACLs for operation: read, uid: 6, model: ir.rule 
2019-10-21 12:29:19,278 8537 INFO sample odoo.addons.base.models.ir_model: Access Denied by ACLs for operation: read, uid: 6, model: ir.rule

Comment: `id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_test_test,access_test_test,model_test_test,base.group_user,1,1,1,1`

Reqwrite your `ir.model.access.csv` like above.